# Python Server-Client Communication with each other

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am trying to modify a tcp/ip server-client communication. Only the server can communicate with the client. I am trying to find an easy a way to send a message back to the server. Not a chat !! Just a server which will send data to a client and receive data from the client.

I am using this example :

Server:

```
    host="my_ip"
    port=4446                  
    from socket import *              
    s=socket()
    s.bind((host,port))                 
    s.listen(1)                         
    print "Listening for connections.. "
    q,addr=s.accept()               
    var = 1
    while var == 1 :
         data=raw_input("Enter data to be send:  ")  
         q.send(data)  
    s.close()
```

Client:

```
    host="my_ip"
    port=4446 
    from socket import *
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,port))
    var = 1
    while var == 1 :  
         msg=s.recv(1024)
         print "Message from server : " + msg
         #response = "Message delivered"   # Response to be send 
         #s.sendto(response(host,port)) 
    s.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered using ZeroMQ ? It is extremely easy to use and has built in all kinds of fantastic things like making sure the client never receives unfinished messages, and it is fast, extremely fast. It is also environment free, which means you can write the client or server in any language you feel like. I suggest you give it a try. You can also try a redis server, it has fantastic PUB SUB system built in, and it is so easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Python actual has a built in class to make your life a bit easier. http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question however; you can simply send data back to the server in the same way you had the server send data to the client.

Comment: The inly thing that I need and I cannot find is a way for the client to send back something ... I cannot find a way to do it. I am using the .send and .recv but i get an error :A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Answer (score 0):

Use sock.sendall().  Also, you shouldn't just name a var "var" as it doesn't describe what it does.  I would create a boolean instead and name it something like, "isListening" or "isSending".